# How to organize table for storing History in DB?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

How can I organize additional table/tables for storing `Order History`?

Right now my DB structure is very simple, see code below:

```
CREATE TABLE category_table (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name CHARACTER(250)     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE order_table (
  id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  total_price    DECIMAL(12, 2),
  date           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
  product_amount INT
);

CREATE TABLE product_table (
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY             NOT NULL,
  name        CHARACTER VARYING(250)         NOT NULL,
  price       DECIMAL(12, 2),
  category_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT category_fk FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category_table (id)  
);

CREATE TABLE product_order_table (
  product_id INT,
  order_id   INT,
  CONSTRAINT product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_table (id),
  CONSTRAINT order_fk FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES order_table (id)
);
```

I need to organize table/tables for `Order History` regarding to these two restrictions:

  1. We can delete records form table `order_table`

  2. We can change records in `order_table`

I need advice in a DB design.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to keep tracking the history with another table "order_table_history".

Create trigger function for this table "order_table" and on any operation like insert/update/delete the trigger insert one record in the history table "order_table_history".

Also you can add more columns in the history table, like "user_id/user_name" or "operation_status=delete/update".

```
CREATE TABLE order_table_history (
  id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  order_id       INT,
  total_price    DECIMAL(12, 2),
  date           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
  product_amount INT
);
```

Comment: Actually I not familiar with `trigger functions`.

Comment: You cand read some examples on this links: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html or    http://www.postgresqltutor.com/create-trigger.html